# Text not showing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this code that is supposed to show a h4 that says that there are no products if the search query doesn't match any strings. I now have this weird bug where my text isn't showing. It is available in the html and css (console) and works after I click on an element that has a click() binded or edit the color in css ( console ). Does anyone know what this could be and how I could fix this, have tried tons of stuff but nothing seems to help?

I am adding it like this ->

```
<h4 ng-show="filteredItems.length == 0"  class="explanation">We found no products</h4>
```

css

```
h4 {
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 20px;
  }
```

Search

```
$scope.searchItem = function( query ) {
    foundItems = [];
    query.toLowerCase();
    if( searchTimeout )
      $timeout.cancel( searchTimeout );

    searchTimeout = $timeout( function() {
      for( var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++ ) {
        if( $scope.items[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf( query ) > -1 ) 
          foundItems.push( $scope.items[i] );
      }

      $scope.filteredItems = foundItems;   

    }, 400);
  }
```

*EDIT*

```
    // fill with dummy data
      $scope.define = function() {
        var random;
        for( var i = 0; i < 114; i++ ) {
          random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
          var text;
          switch( random ) {
            case 1:
                text = 'Double espresso';
                break;
            case 2:
                text = 'Frappuccino cookie crumble chocolate'
                break;
            case 3:
              text = 'Cappuccino'
                break;
            case 4:
              text = 'Very Berry Hibiscus Starbucks Refreshers™ Beverage'
              break;
            case 5:
              text = 'Clover® Brewed Coffee Coffee Traveler'
              break;
            case 6:
              text = 'Featured Dark Roast'
              break;
            default:
                text = 'Not defined'
          }
          $scope.data.items.push( { name: text, image: random } );
        }
// THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM ( uncommented everything works )
        //$scope.data.filteredItems = $scope.data.items;
      }
      $scope.define();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLKk9FP5pwttcq9ACXMv). I have it running and doing what I think you want it to. I always preface any scope values i.e. `$scope.data.query` instead of just `$scope.query`. This helps to keep the view from trying to use a value on its scope instead of the controller's scope.

Also, since you are using an ng-model, I didn't see the reason of passing the value from the view to the controller seeing as the controller already has it. This is why ng-change now only calls `searchItems()`

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to check it out. Great tips. ty again ;)

Comment: I have tried to break it, but I haven't been able to do so successfully... :s

Comment: Hey @owen I think I've solved my problem but I don't know why it affects my code. Do you know wy? I've added an EDIT above

Comment: I've put your code into the plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rsoP69R20C5BIrr1SKiA?p=preview I have it working both commented and uncommented. With the line that you commented out, the list displays everything because you assigned every item to filteredItems. Commenting the line out displays no products found until a search is performed. Is your program working differently?

Comment: Nope does that too. But when I uncomment it it isn't having the bug where my input and text doesn't show. I don't have a clue why.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with using `data.` as in `data.filteredItems`. When you don't preface with a container object, the view can impart its scope instead of using the controller's scope. i.e. `ng-show="filteredItems.length"` actually creates `filteredItems` in a child scope on the view that inherited from the controller's parent scope. `data.filteredItems` tells the view to use the item from the controller's scope.

Comment: When you're ready to confuse yourself even more, read this article on Angular scopes: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Comment: Thanx. I am going to look into it!